# Frobenius matrix norm vs. 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, factoring

From [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring12/cos598C/svdchapter.pdf#page=7) article about the singular value decomposition:

*Let $A$ be an $n \times d$ matrix and think of the rows of $A$ as $n$ points in $d$-dimensional space. The Frobenius norm of $A$ is the square root of the sum of the squared distance of the points to the origin. The 2-norm is the square root of the sum of squared distances to the origin along the direction that maximizes this quantity.*

Can someone help me to understand this remark? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first says
$$\Vert A \Vert_F^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \Vert p_k - 0 \Vert_2^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^d (p_k)_i^2$$
which is true if $(p_k)_i = A_{ki}$.
For the latter a similar thing holds considering $\Vert A \Vert_2^2 = |\lambda_{\max}|$; Mathematically put and implying a "direction" vector to be normalized, it says
$$\Vert A \Vert_2^2 = \sup_{\Vert x\Vert_2 = 1} \Vert Ax \Vert_2^2 = \sup_{x\in \mathbb R^d \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\Vert Ax \Vert_2^2}{\Vert x\Vert_2^2}$$
Which coincides with the definition of the $2$-Norm as the induced Operator norm and the last equality holds due to continuity and linearity of the Operator $x\mapsto Ax$.

Comment: I understand what you have written, but I'm not sure how this connects to "the sum of squared distances to the origin along the direction that maximizes this quantity". I don't see any sums of squared distances (i.e. distances in $\mathbb{R}^n$) showing up in the second part.

Comment: @EricAuld Note that $\Vert x \Vert_2^2$ is the squared distance of $x$ from the origin in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. a sum of squared $\mathbb R$-distances from $0$.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks for the answer. Just want to ask that does it mean in plain terms that in 2-norm we are allowed to take one vector x and find the frobenius form for A*x which is projection of A along x.. The task is to find the best of these x's ...

Comment: @AshishNegi The Frobenius norm isn't defined for the vector $Ax$, so I can't understand your question.

Comment: i thought that 2-norm is special type of frobenius norm ?? and if i rephrase my last coomment as : " in 2-norm we are allowed to take one vector x and find the `2-form` value for A*x which is projection of A along x.. The task is to find the best of these x's"  would this be right now ?

Comment: @AshishNegi Without telling what "best" should mean in this context, I can't say much. Also $Ax$ can't really be called a projection of $A$ along $x$.